# Flowplayer user choose bitrate - like Youtube

Tags: html, select, flowplayer, bitrate

I would like to extend Flowplyer HTML controls with choose bitrate functionallity - like on Youtube. So user would get list of possible bitrates (from Wowza) and then he could switch between different bitrates.

Is that even possible in Flowplayer. Is there any example of this functionallity?

best Matej

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

You have to append this html to player area.

...

and than everything works. Function showQualityChoises() sets visible  true or false on elements ENCODE00 - ENCODE0X.